# Which is the better & faster way in python?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

**Which way is faster in python?**

```
if status=='Failed' or status=='Terminated' or status=='Aborted' or status=='Expired':
   break
```

or

```
if status in ['Failed', 'Terminated', 'Aborted', 'Expired']:
   break
```

Comment: Unless you're writing some kind of super-performant code, always opt "readable" over "micro-optimized". The second one is much more readable/maintainable.

Comment: If you change the latter option to a set instead of a list it'll be O(1), making it as fast as possible, _and_ readable/maintainable.

Comment: What O notation do we say the `status in list` is?

Comment: @PeptideWitch I think we say [it's O(n)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: The first option can be the best performer if one of the options dominates. Lets say that things terminate 99% of the time. Put that one first and the others don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is slightly faster if you tend to fail the comparison in the first/second entry. That's likely because the `CONTAINS_OP` is a single bytecode operation and goes into mostly-native code for iterating the list. The first solution is checking each comparison in pure python which has some unnecessary overhead.

But the difference is trivial and the overall time is usually ~0.3 μs per the whole check on my system, so it either shouldn't matter in practice, or the code should not use Python in the first place.

You should test questions like that yourself. You can wrap your code in time checks:

```
def first(rep):
    status='foobar'
    for x in range(rep):
        if status=='Failed' or status=='Terminated' or status=='Aborted' or status=='Expired':
            pass

rep = 1000000
start = time.perf_counter()
first(rep)
diff1 = time.perf_counter()-start
```

and compare the results.